# Show Drop Down list for country in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have To show drop down list of country in textfield in ios.How should i show this list?

Comment: You can use tableview for the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a down arrow like UIButton at the right end of your `UITextField`.
2. On the click of this button you'll have to load a `UIView` or `UITableView` which will come exactly down to your text field.
3. This custom `UIView` or `UITableView` will act as your drop down.
4. Once your use is complete you can either hide it or remove it.

There are a lot of other ways which you can use instead of using a Drop Down. I'd suggest you to use those methods if possible.

You can refer [this](http://code.google.com/p/dropdowndemo/downloads/detail?name=dropdowndemo.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: how to get all country list?

Comment: @sharmaravi : there are API's available which gives you list of countries in XML as well as JSON format. Just google for it.